# Jupyter is executed, but no result is shown

Tags: python, algorithm, nlp, matcher

I run a NLP Text Matching algorithm. It turns out that sometimes it does not show the output after the successful running.

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab, validate=True)

patterns = [{"LOWER": {"IN": ["self employed", "average"]}}, {"OP": "?"},  {"OP": "?"}, {"OP": "?"}, {"LOWER": {"IN": ["self employed", "average"]}}]
    
matcher.add("Self Employed", None, patterns)
    
doc = nlp(u"I am a self employed person with an average income; An average self employed project")
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
        rule_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # get the unicode ID, i.e. 'CategoryID'
        span = doc[start : end]  # get the matched slice of the doc
        print(rule_id, span.text)
```

What is the reason? Is there anything related to the algorithm? Thank you

Comment: Is there anything in the `matches` variable? Can you print `len(matches)`?

Comment: Yes, it is 0. Does it mean no matching item? why there are no matching items? Thank you

Comment: I've never used that library, so I can't help you.